# Nagelkerke value equals 1. Why?

Tags: regression, logistic, stata

I have run a logistic regression model, which leads to acceptable results (e.g., McFadden's R2 >10%). However, the Nagelkerke value is always 1, which seems like a failure to me (using the comand "fitstat" in stata). Do you know where this comes from? The Maximum Likelihood R2 is also always reported as 1.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Please find attached the Outputs (.logistic ... and .fitstat)

```
Logistic regression     Number of obs   =   71932
        LR chi2(18) =   8542.38
        Prob > chi2 =   0.0000
Log likelihood = -38017.275     Pseudo R2   =   0.1010




. fitstat

Measures of Fit

Log-Lik Intercept Only:   -42288.463     Log-Lik Full Model:       -37993.107
D(71907):                  75986.213     LR(24):                     8590.713
                                         Prob > LR:                     0.000
McFadden's R2:                 0.102     McFadden's Adj R2:             0.101
Maximum Likelihood R2:         1.000     Cragg & Uhler's R2:            1.000
McKelvey and Zavoina's R2:     0.159     Efron's R2:                    0.125
Variance of y*:                3.914     Variance of error:             3.290
Count R2:                      0.754     Adj Count R2:                  0.103
AIC:                           1.057     AIC*n:                     76036.213
BIC:                     -728184.032     BIC':                      -8322.310
```

---

*(Edit: copying information from non-answer / response below.)*  Here you find the Stata output:

```
. fitstat

Measures of Fit for logistic of return

Log-Lik Intercept Only:   -42288.463     Log-Lik Full Model:       -38017.275
D(71913):                  76034.549     LR(18):                     8542.378
                                         Prob > LR:                     0.000
McFadden's R2:                 0.101     McFadden's Adj R2:             0.101
Maximum Likelihood R2:         1.000     Cragg & Uhler's R2:            1.000
McKelvey and Zavoina's R2:     0.159     Efron's R2:                    0.125
Variance of y*:                3.910     Variance of error:             3.290
Count R2:                      0.753     Adj Count R2:                  0.102
AIC:                           1.058     AIC*n:                     76072.549
BIC:                     -728202.797     BIC':                      -8341.075
```

I work with a very high n. Is this a possible reason?

Comment: Can you add the output of the `logit`, the `fitstat` and its version (which you can get with `which fitstat`)?

Answer (score 5):

The Nagelkerke $R^2$ come from comparing the likelihood of your full specification to an intercept-only model. The formula is

$$R^2_N=\frac{1-\left( \frac{L_{intercept}}{L_{full}} \right)^{2/N}}{1-L_{intercept}^{2/N}}.$$

This measure is also called Cragg-Uhler $R^2$. Whenever the full model perfectly predicts success and has a likelihood of 1, this measure will be one.

Similarly, we have ML (or Cox-Snell) one:

$$R^2_{ML}=1-\left( \frac{L_{intercept}}{L_{full}} \right)^{2/N}.$$

The former has a denominator dividing the latter that makes sure that its range includes 1. It is very strange that your ML $R^2$ has a value of 1 since the maximum possible value is $1-L_{Intercept}^{2/N}$, which should be less than one. In fact, the [max is $3/4$](http://statisticalhorizons.com/r2logistic).

Finally, for completeness sake: 
$$R^2_{McF}=1-\left( \frac{ \ln L_{full}}{\ln L_{intercept}} \right).$$

---

**Update:**

This seems to be a numerical problem with this command in Stata. Doing it by hand with `display` also fails:

```
. display  (1-(exp(-42288.463)/exp(-37993.107))^(2/71932))/(1-exp(-42288.463)^(2/71932))
.
```

If I take your log likelihoods and plug them into Wolfram Alpha after exponentiating, I get [$R^2_{ML}=0.11$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+1-%28exp%28-42288.463%29%2Fexp%28-37993.107%29%29%5E%282%2F71932%29) and [$R^2_{N}=0.16$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20%281-%28exp%28-42288.463%29%2Fexp%28-37993.107%29%29%5E%282%2F71932%29%29%2F%281-exp%28-42288.463%29%5E%282%2F71932%29%29). It makes sense that the McFadden $R^2$ behaves better since it uses log likelihoods.

Comment: Having that said, $R^2$ of 1 are mostly caused by mis-specified errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It is not possible that my full model would predict success perfectly. I belive it is good, but not that good ;-) Are there other ideas where this could come from and what I could do? Thank you very much in advance. Best regards, Lukas

Comment: @Lukas I don't have any other ideas. Can you report the output of `fitstat` and its version in the body of the question, or at least the 2 likelihood values and the mean outcome?

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot! I could not imagine that Stata would not be able to calculate this. But the numbers themselves are realistic right? Or is the inability of stata a sign for unrealistic, high numbers? Thanks a lot!

Comment: My intuition is that the log-likelihood values are correct since that is native Stata code, which tends to be very good. You can do the calculation by hand using them.